# Java Stream generates more values than limit set

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

For some reason Java Stream generates more values (calls hasNext() and next() methods of iterator.

Here's the synthetic example.

I have a generator in a form of an Iterator:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
static class TestIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final int bound;
    private final Random rnd = new Random();

    private int current = 0;

    @Override public boolean hasNext() {
        return current < bound;
    }

    @Override public Integer next() {
        current = rnd.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Generated: " + current);
        return current;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to have a flattened Stream which consists of few Iterators

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    List<Iterator<Integer>> iterators = asList(
        new TestIterator(18),
        new TestIterator(18),
        new TestIterator(18));
    Stream<Integer> streams = iterators.stream()
        .map(iter -> (Iterable<Integer>) () -> iter)
        .flatMap(iter -> StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false)) // <-- Here the stream of streams is flatten to a single stream of integers and 'parallel' is set to false
        .limit(5); // <-- Here the limit is set

    streams.forEach(i -> System.out.println("***Consumed: " + i));
}
```

And, surprisingly for me, the output is following:

```
Generated: 1
***Consumed: 1
Generated: 19
***Consumed: 19
Generated: 7
***Consumed: 7
Generated: 7
***Consumed: 7
Generated: 7
***Consumed: 7
Generated: 4
Generated: 3
Generated: 8
Generated: 14
Generated: 0
Generated: 16
Generated: 10
Generated: 3
Generated: 19
```

So, Stream generates more results than passed to the consumer in forEach.
Even despite it's explicitly set 'parallel = false'.

In my real-world scenario hasNext() and next() functions are very expensive, taking data from external services.

Can anybody explain how to do a better job on limiting results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075939) which was fixed in JDK 10+ and backported to `openjdk8u222`, thus updating your Java version will address the issue.

Comment: I've updated JDK to 1.8.0_281 and, interestingly, the issue is still there.
It really works well with one iterator converted to a stream, stopping right after consuming of `limit`, but it still doesn't work with a list of streams created from iterators and flattened.

Comment: The problem is - it generates *everything* from the first stream in the chain. But what if the first stream is infinite? Like:
```
    Iterable<Integer> iter = () -> new TestIterator(20);
    Stream<Integer> stream1 = StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false).limit(10);
    stream1.forEach(<do smth>)
```
Then the program will run infinitely (just checked and verified that _281 version is used).

Comment: I've checked this issue on 
java 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)
and everything was working fine with an infinite iterator. Code: https://gist.github.com/geobreze/712f667ae2d53a9307f3ada549dedefa

Comment: Also, just checked this code on 
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
Using docker container `openjdk:8u222-slim-buster` and got following output:
Generated: 9
***Consumed: 9
Generated: 17
***Consumed: 17
Generated: 2
***Consumed: 2
Generated: 8
***Consumed: 8
Generated: 18
***Consumed: 18

Comment: I confirm that using OpenJDK 1.8.0_222_b10 it works perfectly.
My confusion came from the fact that I tried it on ORACLE JDK 1.8.0_281 and the issue is still there.
It's interesting why some bug is fixed in OpenJDK and is not fixed in "official" one.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code here
[image: You have made the integer value bound final]

And because it is an immutable value that the reason your hasNext() function call is running without stop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. What is an immutable value? `current` variable is set inside `next()` method. And even if `hasNext()` will return true all the time, what is the reason for omitting more values than limit set?